# Do I need an app.get() in express server?

Tags: node.js, docker, express, server

I have an app that I'm trying to host on AWS, but the Docker image isn't running correctly, and is outputting `Cannot GET /` on localhost:8080. I was following along with a Udemy class to build it, and this is the server code:

```
import express from "express";
import { readdirSync } from "fs";
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const fileuploader = require("express-fileupload");
const morgan = require("morgan");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();

// db connection
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("DB Connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log("DB Connection Error: ", err));

// middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
//for image upload
app.use(fileuploader());

// route middleware
readdirSync("./routes").map((r) => app.use("/api", require(`./routes/${r}`)));

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`));
```

I did some research, and feel like it could be because there is no `app.get("/", (req, res) => {...})` in the server. Instead, it's inside a `<Route>` in `<App>`. Do I need to add an app.get here, or is the error somewhere else? I included the Dockerfile below as well. As a side note, the docker image does start the server, and the database connects as well, it is just the website itself that won't load.

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

COPY client/package*.json client/
RUN npm run install-client --omit=dev

COPY server/package*.json server/
RUN npm run install-server --omit=dev

COPY client/ client/
RUN npm run build --prefix client

COPY server/ server/

USER node

CMD [ "npm", "start", "--prefix", "server" ]

EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: `app.use("/api"` would put all them routes on `/api`, none on `/`

Comment: That I know, I just don't understand how to bring up the home page with Docker, because nothing is loading at the moment, and doing a regular npm start works fine

Comment: So you know `Cannot GET /` is normal when you don't have a route handler for that route and no error handler, you answered your own question